# Fastest way to get a transaction accepted

Tags: transactions, metamask, gas

Been asking around and everyone I talk to gives me conflicting answers. I have 2 scenarios in which a transaction is sent. Which one would be the fastest to get accepted.

1. Send a transaction with extremely low gas fee(let's say 10 gwei) at 1pm and speed it up to current network gas fee(let's say 100 gwei) at 2pm.

or

2. Send a transaction at 2pm at 100 gwei.

Comment: Speeding up in 1 is exactly the same as 2, for miner it will be a new transaction with higher gas price. if the replaced transaction has a low gas price it won't influence the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Method #1. There's no way that method #2 will be faster, because method #1 is method #2 + a chance for the transaction to confirm earlier.

If you send at 1pm a transaction with 10gwei/gas, if by chance there is low network activity, your transaction will get picked up.

If not, anyway you will speed it up at 2pm, same as method #2.

So you don't lose anything (other than effort) by trying method #1 and then you have a chance of it getting mined earlier with the lower gas price.